"ODataError: One of the provided arguments is not acceptable" when trying to list DocumentSetVersions using Microsoft Graph SDK
I am trying to retrieve a list of DocumentSetVersions for a specific list item in a SharePoint site using the Microsoft Graph SDK, following the official Microsoft documentation here. However, when attempting to make the API call, I encounter an error.
The SharePoint list is a default document library with version control enabled.
I already implemented other api calls with the same GraphClient, siteId and ListId and it worked perfectly fine.
Im sure that the listItemId is correct.

This is the code:
var result = await _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].DocumentSetVersions.GetAsync();

The error returned is:
ODataError: One of the Provided arguments is not acceptable.

Thanks! In the MS Doc is a Element called "comment" that contains the comment of the version changes, but i cant find it in the response object. How do i get that?

@Rukmini Eliah wants to list documentsetversions, calling versions doesn't make sense. List item version is different from document set version

@user2250152 Thanks for pointing it out, got the requirement

Could you use _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId].DocumentSetVersions.ToGetRequestInformation(); and share the url created for the request?

This is the URI for the request
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/company.sharepoint.com%2Ca719e14a-1cc6-4658-9ffc-cfb2df4fdd48%2C8ae4e023-14b5-4470-8fa3-734194106cf7/lists/0236d6d3-f1f4-4597-9a83-e69e3e10c474/items/8/documentSetVersions

Does this help

That doesn't work, I can't find a key called _checkInComment, although my CheckIn surely has one. Thanks for your help anyway!

Try `try
{
var versions = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[listItemId].Versions
.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "fields" };
});
foreach (var version in versions.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Version ID: {version.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Fields JSON: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(version.Fields)}");
}

}`

Yes that works! The version.Fields contains the _CheckinComment. Thank you.

You can read documentSetVersions only for list items that represents a folder. If the list item represents a file, the Graph API will return the error

ODataError: One of the Provided arguments is not acceptable.

Try to read first list item and check the contentType property
var item = await _graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[itemId]
// check content type
item.ContentType.Name


Sorry, I misunderstood the functionality of DocumentSetVersions. I need the version history of a document. For this, ‘.Versions’ is correct and also works correctly. However, it would be nice if I could still retrieve the CheckInComment for each version, so far I have not found any information on this in the MS documentation.

@EliahThommen Thanks for clarification. Try to create a new question about check in comments
